# A jupyter notebook cell takes very very long time

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

[image]

Here is the code,when I run a notebook cell, one cell will takes very long times. It appears once when run two times. But when I abort running this cell, and run again, it will success quickly.
Also, when I abort running this cell, the time of running this cell is 7h52m11s.

[image]

I don't know why this happends.
Add: The notebook ipynb file is big, 4M

Comment: Are you using local kernel and is it jupyter notebook only or jupyter-lab ?

Comment: @YashKumarAtri I used remote kernel, jupyter notebook only

Comment: Are you using any authentication process in mid ? and what is the ping time ?

Comment: @YashKumarAtri No. The remote host is in the local area network.